# Texture randomly scaled up on objext

Tags: texturing, uv

very new to Blender.
I made a brick texture, and applied it to each of these 4 walls, but one randomly scaled up. Used cube projection.

[image: Bricks]
[image: Nodes]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hello, please show your UV Editor, it must have something to do with your UVs

Comment: Something happened to your UVs.  Redo your unwrap (your cube projection.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to moonboots for their comment.
I looked into the UV editor and found that the scale was different.
[image: UVscale]

Don't know why or how this happened, but its an easy fix.
Thanks again